# Eject USB when files are open in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, usb, native-code

We have a program that checks for and ejects USB devices.  The eject works great except for when a file is open.  We are trying to find a way to eject a USB Device even if a file is open knowing that any changes will not be saved.  In our scenario, changes should not be a factor.  Are there any flags that will allow you to override the safe eject that prevents a device from being ejected when files are in use?  I have had no success finding the flags for the following call:

```
NativeCode.CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi(this.DeviceInstanceHandle, IntPtr.Zero, null, 0, 0);
```

If there is an alternative method that is less of a request and more of a demand, please let me know.

Comment: Yanking the drive out should work just fine then.  Tell the user its safe and they will believe you.

Comment: @Boo. It is bad practice to pull out a usb drive while it's in use.

Comment: Only bad when files are open. OP claims they don't care about the open files.

Comment: Very simply, if a file is locked, it is not safe at all, the program locked it for a reason so nothing else could interfere with it.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to Prepare a USB Drive for Safe Removal](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13839/How-to-Prepare-a-USB-Drive-for-Safe-Removal)

An alternative will be to check for the process locking a file on the usb drive and asking the user to close it or close it yourself.

Comment: cool answer. want to add that checking who's locking file is not supported on windows xp systems